# Java: List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

Tags: java, arrays, list

How I can group all lists in list which contains same exact value.

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This list contains list1 list2 list3 and etc....
I want to find if list1.get(0) is the same as list2.get(0) if no check with list3.get(0) and etc... 
Later I need to group lists if I find the same values in each.
For example if true add list1 and list3 and others which were found to

```
  List<List<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now check with list2.get(0) if equal to others if yes group them and add them to anoter:

```
   List<List<String>> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
```

What I achieved so far:

```
    private static void findEqualLists(List<List<String>> list) {

    int i = 0;
    for (List<String> list1 : list) {
        if (!Collections.disjoint(list1, list.get(i))) {
            System.out.println(list1.get(0)+list.get(i).get(0));
        }else{
            System.out.println(list1.get(0)+list.get(i).get(0));
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Value exmaple:

```
list = {{2017-02,jhon,car},{2017-03,maria,car},{2017-03, boy, car}, {2017-01,arya, car}, {2017-02, girl, car}}
```

Output:

```
Group1:
2017-03,maria,car
2017-03, boy, car

Group2:
2017-02,jhon,car
2017-02, girl, car

Group3
2017-01,arya, car
```

Comment: 1. what's the question? 2. what does it mean to "group" lists ? 3. instead of talking about *how* you're doing something, it's better to discuss *what* is it you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to achieve outpoot by giving value

Comment: "similar" and "grouping" are not well defined: are you "grouping" by date only? and again - what does "grouping" mean ?

Comment: _"I want to achieve outpoot by giving value"_  -- Could you translate that, please? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-):

```
private static Map<String, List<List<String>>>
            findEqualLists(List<List<String>> list) {

    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(0)));
}
```

The returned Map will use `l.get(0)` as a unique key, with each corresponding value being a List of only those Lists whose first element matches that key.

Comment: An how I am able to Output returned Map like I showed above?

Comment: @D1's Call the Map’s `values()` method.  You can either print the returned Collection directly, or, if you want curly braces (`{` `}`) instead of brackets (`[` `]`), you can loop through the Collection and build a String yourself.

Comment: yes I understand that I can use values() method, but how I can divide into groups and print it seperatly? I mean that one key now has multiply values, do I need to iterate through every key and then to iterate through that key list to get values for that certain key?

Comment: @D1's One key has multiple values, because there are multiple entries in the original List which start with, for example, "2017-03".  You don’t need to iterate through keys;  you can simply iterate through `values()`, which is already divided into groups.  The whole point of a Map is that each member of `values()` corresponds to exactly one key.

Comment: Yes it will be divided, but I don't get it how you gonna know when that group ended and another started to form?

Comment: First element in `values()` is "[[2017-03, maria, car], [2017-03, boy,  car]]" because its corresponding key is "2017-03".  Second element is "[[2017-01, arya,  car]]" because its corresponding key is "2017-01".  And so on.  Each item in values() is for a *different key* and therefore a different group.